# Deploying multiple 3rd party JARs to global (internal) Maven nexus

Tags: maven, deployment, jar, dependencies, nexus

I have a load of 3rd party JAR files (around 40 different JARs from various SDKs I'm using) sitting in a folder on my hard drive. I want to declare those JARs as dependencies in my future maven projects.

I cannot obtain those JARs from the worldwide global maven repository as you could with e.g. Log4J, JUnit, Velocity etc, since they are not available there.

How do I get these JAR files from my local folder into my company global (but internal) maven repository (Nexus)? What would be the necessary steps? The best solution would be a programmatical one, if that's possible at all.

I'm confused that I could not find any solution to my problem using Google, because I imagine this to be a very widespread problem. So maybe I'm thinking in a wrong direction.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can install the libraries to your local repository with the [maven-install-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/) ([`install-file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) goal - see [example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/installing-secondary-artifacts.html)).

You can deploy the libraries to your remote repository (Nexus) with the [maven-deploy-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) ([`deploy-file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) goal - see [example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html#The_deploy:deploy-file_Mojo)).

You can also use the Nexus web application to upload the libraries to nexus (see [Nexus Book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/) - [Uploading Artifacts](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/using-sect-uploading.html)).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @FrVaBe. Is there any way to do this from Java using any of the Maven APIs? I tried using the Invoker, but according to [the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/), the deploy goal is not supported.

Comment: @HombreFab I have no experience with programmatically executing maven tasks but it should be possible to configure the maven-deploy-plugin in a pom.build.plugin section and trigger the invoker:install goal. In your case the most simple automated method for me seems to be a batch-script which executes the different `mvn deploy:deploy-file` commands.

Comment: Thank you. I'll iterate over my JAR-files in Java and execute the 'mvn deploy:deploy-file' by [calling the commandline](http://www.linglom.com/2007/06/06/how-to-run-command-line-or-execute-external-application-from-java/) from java directly for each file. That'll do it.

Comment: Hello, I've written a small tool which generates a pom.xml for exactly this purpose, perhaps my [blog post "How to bulk install 1000 3rd party JARs to Maven local & deploy to remote repo"](http://blog2.vorburger.ch/2015/02/how-to-bulk-install-1000-3rd-party-jars.html) and the [source of my MavenBulkInstallDeploy project](https://github.com/vorburger/MavenBulkInstallDeploy) could be useful to someone.